# Using NSXML parser how to parse the attribute contents in iphone

Tags: iphone

How do you parse the attribute contents in the XML file below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>

<ROOT_ELEMENT><RESPONSE READ_TAG="LEVEL_LIST" RESULT="" TEXT=""/>
<USER USER_NAME="newadmin01" TOKEN_ID="0.0768059253258988" FULL_NAME="newadmin01, newadmin01"/>
<DATETIME UNFORMATTED_TEXT="Aug 10 2011 10:12PM" FORMATTED_TEXT="10 Aug 22:12"/>
<BREADCRUMB/>
<LEVEL_LIST><LEVEL ID="4519" NAME="Mega Mart" CHILD_EXISTS="Y" ADD_EDIT_PRIVILEGE="Y"/></LEVEL_LIST>
</ROOT_ELEMENT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parser delegate methods `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict` you can get attributes for `elementName` using the `attributeDict`.

`attribute = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"<attribute_name>"];` Replace the string with your attribute name.